# System.Windows.Controls.Image - trying to get a color of the certain pixel

Tags: image, c#-4.0

There's a System.Windows.Controls.Image on WPF form and it has a bitmap. How do I get a color of the certain pixel of `image1.Source` by its coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Bitmap.GetPixel(x, y)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx) method:

> Parameters
>
> x Type: System.Int32 The x-coordinate of the pixel to retrieve.  y
> Type: System.Int32 The y-coordinate of the pixel to retrieve.
>
> Return
> Value
>
> Type: System.Drawing.Color A Color structure that represents the color
> of the specified pixel.

Comment: image1.Source has no GetPixel(x, y) method because it's the type of ImageSource class.

Comment: @AlexMaslakov: What you could do is to first convert the `ImageSource` to a `Bitmap` and then apply the method I proposed. You can take a look here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2007/03/08/bitmapsource-bitmap-interop.aspx to see how you can convert from `ImageSource` to `Bitmap`.